# C: Invalid Memory Access

Tags: arrays, c

I am new to C arrays and I am facing a problem that my code returns an error of invalid memory access.

Here is the exact error:

> "Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access."

Here is my code:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int factorial(int x) {               
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
}

unsigned long long sum_factorial(size_t z, const int array[z]) {
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    
   for (size_t i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
       result = result + factorial(array[z]);  
   }
   
   return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to replace array[z] with array[i] inside the loop to access individual elements of the array correctly.

Comment: Sure hope the array of `int`'s doesn't contain any negative values...

Comment: No the input will be always int array it is given in the problem

Comment: While you're learning, look carefully at the `if/else` in `factorial()`. Consider whether or not you could ditch the `else` completely. Keep the 2x `return`, but no `else`...

Comment: "No the input will be always int array it is given in the problem" You know, integers can be negative, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**small mistake in above code please replace array[z] with array[i] inside for loop ** *Below I mentioned correct code please refer it.*

```
#include <stddef.h>

int factorial(int x) {
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
}

unsigned long long sum_factorial(size_t z, const int array[z]) {
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
        result += factorial(array[i]); // error fix in here,
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but does not explain why the error occurred, nor why the change fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

For a given array `arr` with length `n`, `arr[n]` will always be out of bounds, as arrays are indexed starting at `0`. Accessing out of bounds invokes undefined behavior. The standard doesn't say what should happen, so treat it as though *anything* may happen.

In this case, it seems to be causing a segmentation fault.

```
result = result + factorial(array[z]);
```

Should be:

```
result += factorial(array[i]);
```

The variable `i` *is* constrained so that it will not go out of bounds.

Note also that the base case of your recursion in `factorial` is is `x` is either `0` or `1`, and the recursion converges on this base case by counting *down*. But if `x` starts out less than `0`, the recursion will be unbounded and will likely runaway until a stack overflow occurs.